# Why my hardcoded data is not writing to a file?

Tags: python, csv

```
def write_to_csv():
    newRow = ['P12467','Cat','Ancora','Yes','Yes','D123456','Lost','14/09/2019','30/09/2019','return to owner',"290 Oak Avenue, BS79 8TR"]

    //with open('DADSA 2019-20 CWK A DATA PETS.csv', 'wb') as csv_file:
    with open("DADSA 2019-20 CWK A DATA PETS.csv", mode="a", newline='') as csv_file:
        # reader = csv.reader(csv_file)
        writer = csv.writer(csv_file)
        for row in csv.reader(csv_file):
            if row[0] == newRow[0]:
                writer.writerow(newRow)
```

I am getting this error "for row in csv.reader(csv_file):
io.UnsupportedOperation: not readable" I dont really understand it what it means.

Comment: You're opening the file in `a` mode, which is just for writing. Why are you trying to read from the file?

Comment: Are you trying to replace an existing row in the file? You can't do it like this.

Comment: I am trying to add new record to a file.

Answer (score 1):

You have a typo, you should use newRow, not csvFile, fixed code below:

```
def write_to_csv():
    newRow = ['P12467','Cat','Ancora','Yes','Yes','D123456','Lost','14/09/2019','30/09/2019','return to owner',"290 Oak Avenue, BS79 8TR"]

    #with open('DADSA 2019-20 CWK A DATA PETS.csv', 'wb') as csv_file:
    with open("DADSA 2019-20 CWK A DATA PETS.csv", mode="a", newline='') as csv_file:
        # reader = csv.reader(csv_file)
        writer = csv.writer(csv_file)
        for row in csv.reader(newRow):
            if row[0] == newRow[0]:
                writer.writerow(newRow)
```

Comment: How will this fix the error that he's trying to read from a stream that's only open in append mode?

Answer (score 0):

You can't read from a file opened in `a` mode. That's for appending to the file. You could use `a+` mode, but you'll need to seek to the beginning of the file first.

But if you only want to add a new row, you don't need to read from the file first. Just open the file and write the new row.

```
def write_to_csv():
    newRow = ['P12467','Cat','Ancora','Yes','Yes','D123456','Lost','14/09/2019','30/09/2019','return to owner',"290 Oak Avenue, BS79 8TR"]

    with open("DADSA 2019-20 CWK A DATA PETS.csv", mode="a", newline='') as csv_file:
        writer = csv.writer(csv_file)
        writer.writerow(newRow)
```